# Prove that $gHg^{-1}$ is a subgroup of $G$ of the same order as $H$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, normal-subgroups

Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ and fix some element $g\in G$. Prove that $gHg^{-1}$ is a subgroup of $G$ of the same order as $H$.

Proof: Let $G_H = gHg^{-1}$. Since $H\leq G$ therefore $e\in H$ so $G_H \neq \emptyset.$ Next, we claim for any $ghg^{-1}\in G_H$, we have $(ghg^{-1})^{-1}=gh^{-1}g^{-1}$. Since $H\leq G$ therefore $h^{-1}\in H$ so $gh^{-1}g^{-1}\in G_H$. Then by associativity we have
\begin{align*}
(ghg^{-1})(gh^{-1}g^{-1}) &= gh(g^{-1}g)h^{-1}g^{-1}\\
&= g(hh^{-1})g^{-1}\\
&=gg^{-1}\\
&= e,\\
\end{align*}
so $(ghg^{-1})^{-1}=gh^{-1}g^{-1}$ as claimed. Now for some $h,j^{-1}\in H$ we will have
\begin{align*}
(ghg^{-1})(gj^{-1}g^{-1}) &= gh(g^{-1}g)j^{-1}g^{-1}\\
&= g(hj^{-1})g^{-1},\\
\end{align*}
and since $H\leq G$ we have $hj^{-1}\in H$ so $g(hj^{-1})g^{-1}\in G_H$ and hence $G_H\leq G$.

Next we will show that $|G_H|=|H|$. Define a function $f:H\to G_H$ given by $f(h)=ghg^{-1}$. Choose $x,y\in H$ such that $x=y$. Then we have
\begin{align*}
x &= y\\
gxg^{-1} &= gyg^{-1}\\
f(x) &= f(y),
\end{align*}
so $f$ is well-defined. Moreover, for any $h,k\in H$ we have
$$f(h)f(k)=ghg^{-1}gkg^{-1}=g(hk)g^{-1} = f(hk),$$
which shows $f$ is a homomorphism. To show $f$ is one-to-one, assume for some $n,m\in H$ we have $f(n)=f(m)$. Utilizing the properties of inversion and associativity we then have
\begin{align*}
f(n) &= f(m)\\
gng^{-1} &= gmg^{-1}\\
(g^{-1}g)n(g^{-1}g) &= (g^{-1}g)m(g^{-1}g)\\
n &=m,\\
\end{align*}
so $f$ is one-to-one. Finally, choose any $g_h \in G_H$. Then $g_h = ghg^{-1}$ for some $h\in H$. Then $f(h)=ghg^{-1}=g_h$ so $f$ is onto. We have shown $f$ is a bijective homomorphism and therefore an isomorphism, which implies that $|G_H|=|H|$ as was wanted. $\Box$

Is this correct?

Comment: Correct, but could be more focused on the essential part that $f(h)=ghg^{-1}$ is an automorphism and hence preserves the order as an isomorphism invariant. So $gHg^{-1}\cong H$, which is a subgroup.

Comment: Why do you need the homomorphism part? The bijectivity suffices to the aim. Also the well-definitedness part is pointless. And finally, for the subgroup part, I'd have focused on closure and closure by inverses, only.

Comment: Showing $xy^{-1}$ is in the subgroup accomplishes closure and closure by inverses in one step instead of two.

Comment: @pyridoxal_trigeminus, yes but the one-step test uselessly brings inverses into the game for the finite case, where the closure suffices. That's why I personally prefer the two step as general approach.